# C# How to Access local network (192.168.x.x) within Docker containers

Tags: c#, .net, docker, networking, proxy

This is my first post here, I've looked across the internet in order to solve this issue but have no idea how to do this, as i am new to docker and not that great at networking (saying kindly).

I need a way to access my host machines internal network IP which has been forwarded to a port that connects to a proxy server. so essentially 192.168.x.xx:5000 => someproxyserver.com
now when setting up the SOCKS5 on my local machine or even in C# it is able to connect and it works.
but this is not the case with docker, again i am complete noob at docker, i have tried many things, but i can't seem to get my docker container to connect to the socks5 server.

I even tried to run the docker container with `--network=host` but i get an error (no route to host)
Ideally i would not want to use --network host as i have many other containers connecting to a external network.

```
var settings = new ProxySettings() {
  Host = localIp,
  Port = port
};
using (var proxyClientHandler = new ProxyClientHandler<Socks5>(settings)) {
  using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(proxyClientHandler)) {
    var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://api.ipify.org?format=json");
  }
}
```

this is the C# code which i am using to connect to the SOCKS5 server.

When using `--network=host`

[image]

without `--network=host`

[image]

Comment: Usually docker creates a bridge network which allows access to the local network of the host to the container if you don't specify the --network flag. Can you post any exceptions ?

Comment: @vasiloreshenski Hey thanks for getting back to me, I've updated the post and added the exceptions received

Comment: have you tried running your code in a simple console application outside of a container?

Comment: Also, please post your `docker run` command that's triggering the exception

Comment: Without docker container it works fine, and for the docker run command I'm just using docker run --network=host within visual studio in the csproj file

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make this work somehow, without including any run commands, i believe this was failing due to my firewall blocking access, it was weird as i did allow access to it, however after restarting my computer earlier on, it worked :) so yeah if anyone stumbles across this, just remember to make sure your firewall isn't blocking access to docker